# Scroll bar of fonts list is not shown in Word and Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, scrollbar

Since last hour or so I ran into a problem with Word and Excel.

The scroll bar of fonts list has disappeared! So that I can't scroll the list quickly.

What do you think the problem is?

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Comment: The arrows for the scrollbar are visible

Comment: The display is far from quick, not like the desktop application. You are using Word online, and I assume Excel online.

Comment: As it started to appear recently, please restart your pc, that generally helps.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon No, it's actually offline windows version.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I've already done it, but it didn't work

Comment: The online version is a browser version and it does not depend on platform https://support.office.com/client/Differences-between-using-a-document-in-the-browser-and-in-Word-3E863CE3-E82C-4211-8F97-5B33C36C55F8

Answer (score 1):

You could try :

- Reboot twice and check if the problem still exists
- Repair Office in *Control Panel > Programs and Features* by right-click
  and select Change
- Uninstall and re-install Office.